# Need chewiness and density added to blondies no carbs

Tags: baking, low-carb, keto

I want chewy and dense blondies. The recipe I'm currently using is:

```
2 cups almond flour
1 cup xylitol sweetener
2 eggs
½ cup butter
vanilla extract
```

I've tried adding ground flaxseed, corn syrup and corn starch. No xanthan gum please, as it's too expensive!

Comment: Can you describe the texture of the result you're getting now from the above recipe? (So we know what your starting point is). Are they crumbly, or cakey, or brittle, or ...?

Answer (score 1):

Try powdered gelatin. Using these two recipes as reference ([1](https://peaceloveandlowcarb.com/keto-chewy-chocolate-chip-cookies/), [2](https://trinakrug.com/keto-chocolate-chip-cookie-bars/)) I recommend you start with a tablespoon.

In candy making, gelatin is a very common way to create chewy textures, like in gummy candy or marshmallow. It turns out it can do just the same in baking. While candy recipes generally require you to "bloom" the gelatin powder to avoid clumping, this can be avoided in our case: you can simply whisk the powdered gelatin in with the rest of your dry ingredients.

Gelatin is a protein, so it definitely meets your zero carb requirement. It is also inexpensive when purchased in bulk (the tubs are usually cheaper than the packets).